# SQl sum items conditionally

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ms-access

I have the below code. It counts 1 if it is certain work and 0 if it is other work. I need a way to count 0.5 if it is a third work. I have tried this and it always seems to count in whole numbers. Is there a way to do this using SQL? I have searched and cannot find such a way to calculate some items as 0.5. This is going to help with production totals in a access database

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
 [Type of Work],
COUNT(case when  [Type of Work] IN 
('LEP Decisions',
'Creditable Coverage',
'Pends','Demographics',
'Consents','POA','PCP','Housing Verifications',
'LEP Cases') 
then 1 else Null END)as count
  ,[User ID]
FROM [Medicare_Enrollment].[dbo].[Sample]
group by [Type of Work], [User ID]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest changing `COUNT` to `SUM` (and thus summing up `1`, `0.5` or `0` - instead of counting `Null`):

```
  select top 1000 
         [Type of Work], 
         sum (case 
                when [Type of Work] in ('LEP Decisions','Creditable Coverage','Pends','Demographics','Consents','POA','PCP','Housing Verifications','LEP Cases') then 
                  1
                when [Type of Work] in ('SOME OTHER WORK', 'THIRD WORK') then
                  0.5  
                else 
                  0 -- nothing to add 
              end) as count,
         [User ID]
    from [Medicare_Enrollment].[dbo].[Sample]
group by [Type of Work], 
         [User ID]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
[Type of Work], 
SUM(case when  [Type of Work] IN ('LEP Decisions','Creditable Coverage','Pends','Demographics','Consents','POA','PCP','Housing Verifications','LEP Cases') then 1 
WHEN [Type of Work] IN ('') -- Put your work list
THEN 0.5
else 0 END)as count
,[User ID]
FROM [Medicare_Enrollment].[dbo].[Sample]
group by [Type of Work], [User ID]
```

Comment: I believe COUNT also should be replaced by SUM

Comment: Oh yeah. My mistake.